# How to view e-mails without internet connections?

Tags: email

If I want to make a secure PC that has zero network connection, how can I view my e-mails on it? Are there any tricky solutions to still view my e-mails while I have no network connection? And all that in a secure way?

Thinking of that I have another PC with network connection and a flashdrive?

The original problem is that I want to protect the informations on the secure PC.

Comment: you can normally export your mail box and open it up in the same application I.E outlook or mail ... is what i do when moving emails.

Comment: If you want to protect the airgapped computer, don't move media from insecure computers to it. You could end up infecting yourself.

Comment: Print out the e-mails from the insecure computer and tape them to the screen of the secure computer. BAM! Solution. That'll be $699.95 . Cash only. Nonsequential serial numbers.

Comment: Assuming you have some very special need, you can 
1. try printing and scanning emails 
2. using screen capture (taking digital photo of screen) using camera only attached to "secure" PC.
These can also be susceptible to digital image processing based attacks but definitely "more" secure than connecting to internet.

Comment: @jhash `Assuming you have some very special need` ...Harsh.

Comment: @Loukios, See https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2013/10/air_gaps.html

Answer (score 4):

What you are speaking about is an airgap, a device or network with no network connections outside of its own loop.

If you had an email client within the airgap then you could view emails that have been transferred over to the airgapped system on removable media, but you could still be infected by any malware that is contained within them.

A well known example of this is the famous 'stuxnet' malware. Although the exact delivery mechanism was not email,  it was targeted malware that was suspected to have breached the airgap via removable media.

The airgap itself will mitigate against many types of malware, even if it is successfully delivered. For example, droppers, c2 bots and other malware that requires an Internet connection to function and/or spread will not be able to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Configure an email client to store emails in your flash drive. Connect it to secure computer when needed to read it. Connect it to the other computer when mails need syncing.

I know there are other possible threats to this system arising from the usage of the flash drive.

Minimise them as much as possible: Encrypt the complete flash drive with passphrases and keyfiles, use strong end point protection with firewall, HIPS, anti-virus and anti-malware.